# Key-Value parameter matching with wildcards

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, wildcard

I have a large amount of Key-Value parameters that map to a file path. Most have the following form

```
filepath : /some/path
param_name_1 => 1234
param_name_2 => qwerty
```

But others can contain wildcard characters

```
filepath : /other/path
param_name_1 => 123*4
param_name_2 => ab?12
```

Where the `?` is a wildcard matching any one character and `*` is a wildcard matching 0+ characters.

My users can provide their own set of KV parameters which I have to match and return the mapped path.

Example: User provides

```
param_name_1 => 1234
param_name_2 => qwerty

Application returns /some/path
```

User provides

```
param_name_1 => 123asdqweqweqdqweq1231asdcase4
param_name_2 => abW12

Application returns /other/path
```

For all the mappings that don't contain wildcards, I can compute `hashCode()` for my stored mapping and for the user-provided one and do a `HashMap` lookup which is extremely fast (3-4 parameters to match, 100000 mappings, in 0 milliseconds, it's a hash after all).

For mappings that contain wildcards though, I'm kind of stuck with doing linear look-ups through a list of all mappings that contain wildcards. There are about 2000-5000 such mappings and each look-up takes just under 200 milliseconds and I need to speed it up.

Is there a way I can do a general look-up to match wildcards or some other matching technique that would combine all mappings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`, you can do a prefix search to reduce the number of items you have to iterate through. Just grab the characters that appear before the `*` or `?`, and iterate through all keys that start with those characters. This won't work, of course, if your search term starts with a wildcard.

The other common approach to this problem is to use character `ngrams` or some trie-based structure, but that's a lot more complicated.

Comment: With the kind of data set I'm working on, `ngrams/trie structure` might be to large with all possible combinations. I'll look into using the prefix `TreeMap`.